# The equation $y^2=x\pm \ell $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

For what odd primes $\ell$ does the equations $y^2=x\pm \ell$ have a finite set of solutions over the integers. Here, assume  $y$ is even and $x$ is a prime number.
I am not sure if this is really hard or no but the most obvious thing we see is that $x\equiv \mp \ell [4]$. Otherwise, I don't know how to proceed.
Thank you for any help / hint !

Comment: When you say "I assume x is prime", is that a given condition of the question, or is that something which you think must happen?

Comment: @CalvinLin This is something you can assume from the setting of my problem.

Comment: I read it as: the OP is interested in all pairs $(y,x)$ where $y$ is even and $x$ is prime, satisfying $y^2=x\pm l$ for a given $l$.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want both $x+\ell$ and $x-\ell$ to be squares? or do you want $\ell$ such that either $x+\ell$ or $x-\ell$ is square infintely often, but not necessarily both simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is unknown even in the case $y^2=x-1$ (Landau problem).  It is unknown for all non-obvious cases also.An obvious case is an equation of the form $y^2= x+r^2$. You can read about the more general Bunyakovsky conjecture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: The question was about x +/- l for some prime l, so it would be unknown for all the cases that OP asked about.

Comment: Yes, it is a well known open problem for every non-obvious $l$, not just primes.